# trying mysql.server.local in jsp datasource

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

im new to jsp. im trying to set datasource for mysql from local domain to be fetch in my jsp page. unfortunately, it doesnt return error, it just return the blank page. am i do it wrong?

btw im using jboss eap 6

here is my test.jsp

```
<sql:setDataSource var="datasource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.server.local:3306/javabilling"
     user="jfa"  password="p@ssw0rd"/>  
        <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${datasource}">
            SELECT username, password FROM login
        </sql:query>
        <c:forEach var="display" items="${result.rows}">
            ${display.username} ${display.password}
            <br>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Is there any data in the login table. I mean if you run that SQL SELECT query manually from MySQL command line does it produce any results?

Comment: check driver jar, db permissions

Comment: @anttix, i got several testing username n password n i produce result by using workbench. Leo, no cant do as im not the person to hold the entire local domain.